# Trying to make a button in JavaScript but it's not working

Tags: javascript

I'm new in JavaScript and I took an app here to learn how to use the language.
So, In my index.html I have this code here:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
  <h3>Reset Score</h3>
  <button type="button" id="resetscore">Reset</button>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function reset() {
    localStorage.setItem('total_win', 0);
    localStorage.setItem('total_lose', 0);
  }
  </script>
</div>
```

and this as footer:

```
`<div id="scores" class="ui-grid-b">
<div class="ui-block-a">Tries left:<span id="tries_left">4</span></div>
<div class="ui-block-b">Total win:<span id="total_win">0</span></div>
<div class="ui-block-c">Total lost:<span id="total_lose">0</span></div>
</div>`
```

What I'm basically trying to do is just reset the score to zero. But It's not working...
I tried to put some alert() inside reset() function but didn't work also.

Does someone has a clue why this is happening?
Thanks for helping!

Comment: you've declared the function reset(), but you don't call it anywhere

Comment: So basically the function is never called. Have you added a listener?

Comment: Are you expecting the spans to automatically update the content to match your localStorage variables?

Comment: The code you've posted works if you call the function (http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/946brc9x/), but it's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, because it's a game. When I'm winning or losing it's working. But for this function is not...

Comment: Do you see that the fiddle works?

Comment: I tried the fiddle but it didn't work... Because if you start total_win and lose they don't get change with this function.

Comment: You have no code to change anything. The only thing the code you posted does is set to localStorage variables. You have no code to update the HTML -- it's not automatic.

Comment: So that's it. I need to overwrite my html code?

Comment: You need to write to to read the localStorage variables and then update the DOM.

Comment: Got it now. But it's not working...I think my problem is bigger than that. Even function reset() { alert('working')} doesn't do anything...It's like the JavaScript it's not "working"in this file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an event listener for the click event.

Because of your comment, you can change the DOM by changing the inner HTML, see below snippet and code:

```js
document.getElementById('resetscore').addEventListener('click',function() {
            //localStorage.setItem('total_win', 0);
            //localStorage.setItem('total_lose', 0);
            document.getElementById('total_win').innerHTML = 0;
            document.getElementById('total_lose').innerHTML = 0;
          });
     document.getElementById('win').addEventListener('click',function(){
            var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('total_win').innerHTML);
            document.getElementById('total_win').innerHTML = (a+1).toFixed(0);
});
   document.getElementById('loss').addEventListener('click',function(){
           var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('total_lose').innerHTML);
            document.getElementById('total_lose').innerHTML = (b+1).toFixed(0);       
});
```

```html
<div data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>Reset Score</h3>
      <button type="button" id="resetscore">Reset</button>
      <button type="button" id="win">+1 Win</button>
      <button type="button" id="loss">+1 Loss</button>
    </div>
    <div id="scores" class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">Tries left:<span id="tries_left">4</span></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">Total win:<span id="total_win">0</span></div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">Total lost:<span id="total_lose">0</span></div>
    </div>
```

your script tag can't be inside a div. You need to move all your javascript to the end of your body, right before its closing tag, after all the html

Comment: I've edited the answer. It's not quite clear what you are trying to do, You are aware that the changes your reset function does only update local storage, not the DOM @brunerva

Comment: I want to change the DOM. Because it's counting the victories and loses

Comment: Edited it again, now it's changing. You can remove the plus and minus buttons. I've disabled local storage for the demo, simply uncomment the lines if you need it. @brunerva

Comment: Thank you @michael, I got it now. But, as I said, I think my problem is bigger than that. I can not see why this code it's not running...

Answer (score 1):

Use onclick property:

```
<div data-role="collapsible">
      <h3>Reset Score</h3>
      <button type="button" id="resetscore" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      function reset() {
        localStorage.setItem('total_win', 0);
        localStorage.setItem('total_lose', 0);
      }
      </script>
    </div>
```

You are declaring the function but not calling it anywhere. So you need to call the function at `onclick` event of button.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="reset()" id="resetscore">
```

You need to tell which one of your functions to use, notice the `onclick`, it does just that, so reset executes on click

Comment: I did it and still not working. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Your button needs to call reset

`<button type="button" id="resetscore" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>`

Comment: I did it and still not working. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Whats not working? Is reset getting called? I did not try to fix your reset function but I would not use localstorage.  You could do something like 'document.getElementById("total_win").innerHTML = 0'